# How is the easiest way to check if the response to the request is succesful or not?

Tags: java, android, httprequest, httpresponse, synchronous

I need a simple synchronous function that checks if the response to a specific url is successful or returns an error, for example 404.

For example:

https://api.com/articles/1 -> response returns sth with code 200

https://api.com/articles/1 -> response returns error 404

Comment: What means `successful`?

Comment: @KunLun it means the code will be 200

Comment: The status code will be in the response. That is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was already mentioned in the question, you can check the response status.

- 2xx statuses considered as successful,
- 3xx can be also turn out as
  successful, you should use followRedirect.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Depends on the API, it can return with success status, while the response body has content which could still mean an error.

e.g.: https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-request